# ASP.net MVC controller Action with string parameter doesn't get called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-controller

So, I have a controller Action with this signature

```
  public ActionResult Details(string id) { ... }
```

and a route in my global asax file

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "DevDetails",
            "Dati/Device/Details/{id}",
            new { controller = "Device", action = "Details", id = "" });
```

If and only if I request urls which id ends with '%20' the action controller doesn't get called.

any clues ?

Comment: Do you have another route which matches the request with numbers?

Comment: No I don't, actually the action controller doesn't get called when in the id there are spaces (%20) at the end of the urls.
Thanks for the reply Sjoerd.

Comment: I just trimmed the url before making the request! I didn't need the extra %20 chars